# Проблема рендера ProtectedRoute при перезагрузке приложения. React+RTK

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-dom, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

У меня имеется HOC ProtectedRoute, который не позволяет зайти неавторизованным пользователям на определённые URL, он проверяет авторизован ли пользователь через useSelector

```
function ProtectedRoute() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const token = localStorage.getItem("refresh");

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(checkAuth(token));
  }, [])

  const isLoading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.appReducer.isLoading);
  const isAuth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userSliceReducer.isAuth);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader/>
  }
  return (isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login/" replace={true} />)
};
```

Также данный компонент проверяет, находится ли приложение в стадии загрузки (isLoading) и в случае, если isLoading == true, возвращает компонент Loader (я знаю, что конечно лучше функционал проверки загрузки вынести в отдельный HOC, но оставил так, чтобы не загромождать статью кодом). ProtectedRoute используется в *App.tsx* следующим образом:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
            <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
              // Тут находятся различные Routes, которые не влияют на работу protected route
            </Route>
          </Route>
          <Route path='/login' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
          <Route path='/*' element={<NotFoundPage />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Когда пытаешься зайти на любой Route не авторизованным, то всё работает классно. Но есть проблема, когда обновляешь страницу пользователь сначала видит Loader, потом его перекидывает на Login, а затем на основной Route.
Я уже пытался выносить функционал проверки загрузки в *App.tsx*. И делал следующее:

```
<Route path='/' element={isLoading ? <Loader/> : <ProtectedRoute/>}>
```

Но возникала проблема с тем, что state постоянно обновляется и оба компонента поочерёдно мелькают на экране.
Как решить проблему с "морганием" Login и Loader при перезагрузке, при этом не нарушая принцип работы ProtectedRoute?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я решил данную проблему с помощью переноса логики загрузки в App component:

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const isLoading = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.appReducer.isLoading);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("refresh");
    if (token) {
      dispatch(checkAuth(token));
    }
  }, [])

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader/>
  }

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Suspense fallback={<Loader/>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<ProtectedRoute/>}>
            <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
                 // Routes
            <Route/>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>

    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

А ProtectedRoute теперь выглядит следующим образом:

```
function ProtectedRoute() {
  const isAuth = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userSliceReducer.isAuth);
  return (isAuth ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login/" replace={true} />)
};
```